Can a monk use improved trip and stunning fist in the same round?
Stunning fist states you must declare it before attack. Trip says if you make your trip you make an attack at the same bonus. So if you declare stunning fist could you attempt a trip and then follow it up with stunning fist on your tripped opponent?

Is there a reason that the creature is declaring that it's using a stunning fist attempt before both the trip attack and the followup attack? Why not just wait until after the trip attack and right before the followup attack to declare the followup attack a stunning fist attempt?

Yes
the Stunning Fist Feat gives you one stunning attempt per round (for a certain number of times per day). You can use the Feat for any one of your melee attacks and you declare to do so directly before you make your attack roll. Since you can only stun a foe that takes damage from your attack, it does not make sense to use this feat in conjunction with the Trip special attack.
If you have Improved Trip and get another melee attack attack after a successful trip attempt, you can then declare to use the Stunning Fist Feat for this follow up attack.


You must declare that you are using this feat before you make your attack roll (thus, a failed attack roll ruins the attempt).

(Stunning Fist feat description)
This means that you declare that you are using Stunning Fist immediately before rolling the attack that you want to be a Stunning Fist attack. If you declare you are using Stunning Fist and then attempt to trip, you have wasted the use of Stunning Fist (the trip attack does not deal damage, Stunning Fist only does anything if the declared attack deals damage).
What you want to do, instead, is use trip, and then, once you have succeeded and Improved Trip gives you an extra attack, declare you are using Stunning Fist before that attack roll. Then Stunning Fist applies to the follow-up attack from Improved Trip, and has a chance of doing something (since the follow-up attack is going to at least try to deal damage).
Ultimately, there seems to be some confusion here: Stunning Fist does not require that you declare that you are using it before making any attacks: it requires that you declare it before making the one particular attack that you want to make into a Stunning Fist attack. Contrast the wording with, say, Power Attack:

On your action, before making attack rolls for a round, you may choose […]

(Power Attack feat description)
This makes it clear that you have to declare Power Attack before making any attacks. Stunning Fist does not work the same way. Stunning Fist instead needs to be declared immediately before the particular attack you’re applying it to.
